# Are there any effects time dilation, kinetic or gravitational, has on modern physics and the modern world?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time-dilation

So, I am writing a paper on time dilation and I am basically done with everything, but in the last chapter, I should include which aspects of the modern world and physics are specifically influenced by time dilation. Of course, there are obvious things like satellite etc. But are there any discoveries, experiments,... which wouldn't have been possible without time dilation.
Sorry if it's dumb question, but thank you in advance.

Comment: The GPS would not work without bot special and general realtivity correctionshttp://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~pogge/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html

Comment: Gravity may be described not only as curved spacetime, but also as gravitational time dilation in uncurved, flat space. So the fact that you are attracted by Earth is an effect of gravitational time dilation - See my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/477699/is-curved-spacetime-a-real-thing-or-just-math/477724#477724)

Answer (score 1):

The GPS system requires taking into acount time dilation effects due to the moving satellites  and also gravitational time dilation due to their altitude. Without the GR and SR effects being taken into account, GPS would not work.  Errors would be tens of kilometers per day.

Answer (score 0):

Pions and muons in the atmosphere caused by cosmic rays is a good example of how time dilation was the answer to one of the most known problems in particle physics.