# Is the fabric of space time a real thing?

Tags: gravity, spacetime, curvature

With ny limited intelligence I think Einstein said that the gravity is caused by a curvature in spacetime.But unless there is an actual feelable fabric(or someting similar) how is a curvature caused by an object transmitted through free space ?And if there is in fact such a medium would I "fall" into the curvature caused by the sun if I were anywhere near it(I assume I dont have enough mass to orbit the sun like planets do).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [If the universe is 3D, how is space-time like a “fabric”?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59958/50583)

Comment: Yes, you would fall into the sun if you were near enough.

Comment: But if the sun's curvature even affects Pluto shouldn't I fall even if I was floating in space above the earth.And instead of falling straight wouldn't I fall along that curve like a half U shape?