# why does mass bend spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime

I watched videos on youtube regarding general relativity which say that "imagine a ball kept on a trampoline bends it." But for this explanation, we are using earth's gravity to explain gravity and bend in space time. So how does mass in space bends spacetime as no(negligible) gravity acting on it.

Comment: Relevant xkcd: https://xkcd.com/895/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better explanation of the common general relativity illustration (stretched sheet of fabric)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90592/better-explanation-of-the-common-general-relativity-illustration-stretched-shee)