# Doubt regarding Space-time Grids

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature, visualization

I had a doubt regarding space-time grids... I just don't understand, if the universe is three-dimensional (excluding the time dimension) why do we represent the universe as a single 2D fabric of grids as seen in various internet photos?

*For example, Mercury's orbit tilts 3 dimensionally with respect to the sun, my question is why is it represented as just a single 2D sheet spread across space with respect to the view of the solar system where the universe is 3-dimensional.*

*Earth doesn't have the same orbit positions as compared to other planets, one can be between the $y$ and $z$-axis and the other on the $x$ and $z$-axis, etc. Why is space-time grid just spread across space on a single sheet cause if the coordinates are different we can't form a sheet?*

Why?

Comment: Short answer: such illustrations are extremely misleading. Relevant video: [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://youtu.be/wrwgIjBUYVc)

Comment: Why vote down the question ?  It's a common confusion caused by these visualizations, not the OP's fault.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90592/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Oh come on this wasn't a duplicate... You better read those questions correctly... I asked something different and the other questioner asked something else... Stop reporting answers for no reason...