# The ‘fabric’ of space is what exactly?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

If gravity is mass bending space time, doesn’t a ‘fabric of space’ or some other foundational structure have to exist to be bent in the first place? Why would light travel along a bend in space if space is not made of something?

Comment: The fabric of space is a very common but flawed way to explain the curvature of spacetime and make General Relativity understandable. Here is a couple videos that help make it clear. [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc) and [What is General Relativity?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYq774z4dws)

Comment: The thing is as @mmesser314 said it is a way of explaining general relativity to larger public because obviously it is easier for them to understand rather than throwing bunch of formulae and equation which makes no sense to them!! in reality  it is a mathematical framework that describes the relationship between space and time..

Comment: The unit sphere is curved.   What is the fabric of the unit sphere?

Comment: There’s no fabric. It’s all just geometry.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90592/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: The foundations of physics are measurements and observations. General Relativity is a *model* that successfully reproduces them.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/895/

Answer (score 0):

There is no fabric of spacetime, spacetime itself is a mathematical construct. Great question. It’s a lame overused cliche because no one can come up with anything better than the failed description of General Relativity as a two-dimensional rubber sheet with weighted spheres placed on it in an already existing static gravitational field. It’s a horrible example and a failed attempt in my mind to remove gravity as a force and try to replace it by describing Differential Geometry in physical terms. It may succeed in describing the path of an object, but it certainly does not describe why an object accelerates due to another object no matter how hard and tortuous they get using differential geometry to explain why two objects gravitationally cause each other to accelerate, because there is no static gravitational field existing outside the Universe.