Query regarding the popular demonstration of spacetime curvature
These demonstrations usually begins with some guy taking an table covered with some fabric, put a heavy weight in the middle of it, calls them the "Sun", and makes some marbles ("Planets") go around it, and claims the movement of the marbles happens due the curved nature of the fabric and claims how gravity is not a force, but result of the curvature.
If this is "gravity", then how did their "Sun" cause this curvature, it must have happened due to gravity acting upon it, isn't it?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90592/2451 and links therein.

A new way to visualize General Relativity
