What does a spacetime graph/function actually represent?

Hi all, I'm a beginner to physics stuff and am just learning about space time and general relativity. Often the graph above is used to show a spacetime graph, but I am confused as to what this graph actually means.
Does it represent how much time t passes every "normal" second based on a position x, y, z? But if it did, then gravity wouldn't act as a field force but rather would just multiply your velocity by 1/t (I'm probably wrong about this)? And also, if time were to "slow down" when near a gravitational force, that wouldn't affect your velocity from your own point of reference.
I know this is probably a stupid question, but what is the correct interpretation of this function/graph?

FYI: The picture in your question is not a spacetime diagram. Google for "spacetime diagram" and click on the "images" link to see some real spacetime diagrams.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90592/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13839/2451 and links therein.
