# Is the space-time deformation only a way to say how gravity works?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, curvature

Here we have the classical picture of the deformation of the space-time:

https://blogs.stsci.edu/livio/files/2012/06/spacetime.jpg

And I would to know if this representation is only a way to say how the gravity field of the earth is shaped, and how the gravity works in the area near it, or not.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Maybe he means "Is there another (non-geometric) formulation of gravity that describes it's effects as precisely as General Relativity?" Just guessing though.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3009/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7781/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13839/2451 and links therein.