# How does Einstein's spacetime curvature theory for gravity actually makes sense?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

I have a lot of confusion understanding the concept that a mass creates a curvature in the space time and other small masses gets attracted towards big masses since they starts falling inside that curvature and we feel that it got attracted towards the bigger mass.

But if we let say dig a curved  whole in the ground and if some mass, while passing from its side, falls inside that curve, then it is said that it fell in that curve because of the force of gravity. Then how can we explain the theory of bodies falling in the space time curvature in the name of gravity without the invisible force of gravity which btw Einstein said that it doesn't exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7781/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the curvature of spacetime theory assume gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7781/)

Comment: This might help - [A new way to visualize General Relativity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90592/2451

Comment: Mathematics, mathematics, and more mathematics.  There is no way to explain it properly just using words.