# What would be the implications to physics if Newton was right about gravity?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

I know that Einstein's understanding of how gravity works (and what it is) have been observed to be much more accurate than Newton's, to the point of being considered the truth. Still, what would be some differences in physics (and reality itself) should Newton be right? What things would work differently due to how different the concept of gravity would be and what other mechanics would be affected by this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15990/50583

Comment: Might help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52165/newtonian-gravity-vs-general-relativity-exactly-how-wrong-is-newton

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Newtonian gravitation conflict with special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15990/how-does-newtonian-gravitation-conflict-with-special-relativity)