# How to obtain components of the metric tensor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory, post-newtonian

In coordinates given by $x^\mu = (ct,x,y,z)$ the line element is given

$$ (ds)^2 = g_{00} (cdt)^2 + 2g_{0i}(cdt\;dx^i) + g_{ij}dx^idx^j, $$

where the $g_{\mu\nu}$ are the components of the metric tensor and latin indices run from $1$-$3$. In the **first [post-Newtonian approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Newtonian_expansion)** the space time metric is completely determined by two potentials $w$ and $w^i$. The Newtonian potential is contained within $w$ and the relativistic potential is contained with $w^i$. What I don't understand is:

Often in the literature concerning the **first Post-Newtonian (PN) approximation**, it is just quoted that the components of the metric tensor are given by:

$$\begin{split}g_{00} &=  -\exp(-2w/c^2), \\
g_{oi} &= -4w^i/c^3, \\
g_{ij}&= - \delta_{ij}\left( 1 +2w/c^2  \right).\end{split}$$

Due to the fact that they are often just given without derivation, I'm assuming that I'm missing something very trivial here.

How are these metric components derived?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211930/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm not sure they are related at all. This is a question about the first post newtonian approximation of the metric tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section IV.5.3 *Post-Newtonian approximation* of [Introduction to General Relativity, Black Holes, and Cosmology, Y. Choquet-Bruhat](https://books.google.de/books?isbn=0199666458) discusses a derivation of that metric. It seems to originate from [L. Blanchet and T. Damour, 1989, Post-newtonian generation of gravitational waves](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHPA_1989__50_4_377_0).

The starting point are Einsteins field equations (EFE) in harmonic coordinates and their 1PN expansion and the ansatz
\begin{align}
g_{00}\equiv&-\exp\left(-\frac{2}{c^2} V\right)\\
g_{0i}\equiv&-\frac{4}{c^3}V_i\\
g_{ij}\equiv&\exp\left(+\frac{2}{c^2} V\right)\gamma_{ij}
\end{align}
Using the EFE in harmonic coordinates one can show in 1PN

$$\gamma_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+O(c^{-4}).$$

Further one can find linear  equations relating $V$ and $V_i$ to the source terms:
\begin{align}
\Delta V -\frac{1}{c^2}\partial_t^2V&=-\frac{4\pi G}{c^2} \left(T^{00}+T^{ss}\right)\\
\Delta V_i&=-\frac{4\pi G}{c}T^{0i}.
\end{align}

For details of the involved computation I recommend the book and paper referenced previously and references therein.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I wouldn't say you're missing something 'trivial' - maybe the result is 'standard' in some way that is taken for granted by people who know the field.

The earliest reference containing the result appears to be [Blanchet, Luc, and Thibault Damour. "Post-Newtonian generation of gravitational waves." Annales de l'IHP Physique théorique. Vol. 50. No. 4. 1989](http://archive.numdam.org/article/AIHPA_1989__50_4_377_0.pdf) (see equations $2.10a.$ - $c.$ therein).

The entire derivation is quite involved, but the level of complexity depends on what your starting point is.

In the linked paper the result is derived for the near-field, where the post-Newtonian expansion is assumed valid (i.e. $v/c << 1$, and a weak gravitational field). This allows them to make a number of assumptions, including that $\partial_0 g_{\mu\nu}^{in}/{\partial_i g_{\mu\nu}^{in}} = O(\frac{1}{c})$, where $g_{\mu\nu}^{in}$ is the metric in the inner domain where this near-field expansion is used.

If we start with the Einstein equation in harmonic coordinates, the following set of linearised equations can then be derived:

$\Box\ln(-g^{in}_{00}) = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4}(T^{00} + T^{ss}) + O(\frac{1}{c^6})$

$\Box g_{0i}^{in} = \frac{16\pi G}{c^4}T^{0i} + O(\frac{1}{c^5})$

$\Box g_{ij}^{in} = -\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}\delta_{ij}(T^{0i} + T^{ss}) + O(\frac{1}{c^4})$,

where $\Box$ is the d'Alembertian (using the mostly $+$ metric), and the various components of the energy-momentum tensor $T$ are of known order in $c$.

For convenience the authors then define

$\sigma = c^{-2}(T^{00} + T^{ss})$ and

$\sigma_i = c^{-1}T^{0i}$.

This is a clever trick that allows them to simplify the form of the resultant equations

They then define certain potentials (eq. $2.8$ and $2.9$), from which the desired results follow (along with a number of intermediate intuitive leaps to justify the calculations). These potentials themselves satisfy certain linear equations.

I hope this helps, and apologies for any typos. I think the best thing would be to read the linked paper. It is a bit convoluted, and in a sense I think the result you posted is just one possible parametrisation.

Comment: Haha, it appears my answer was a bit late.

Comment: Wow, it certainly is very involved! I feel the field of PPN is full of only experts (more or less) with very little material for new comers!