# Comparing Theory of Relativity with Newtonian gravity

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity

How does Einstein's General Theory of Relativity compare with Newtonian gravity? How does the curvature of spacetime affect both gravity and the path of light in a planetary system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we recover the Newtonian gravitational potential from the metric of general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211930/)

Comment: If you want a real answer. You've got to read some books. GR is freaking hard.