# Question about the Newtonian limit of general relativity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, approximations

I ran into something peculiar while attempting to carefully derive the Newtonian limit of general relativity, specifically for the geodesic equation.

To set it up, we assume that the curve $q:[a,b]\rightarrow M^{1,3}$ is a timelike geodesic. Then its components satisfy the geodesic equation

$$\frac{d^{2}q^{k}(\tau)}{d\tau^{2}} =-\Gamma^{k}_{ij}\frac{dq^{i}(\tau)}{d\tau}\frac{dq^{i}(\tau)}{d\tau} $$
where the $\Gamma^{k}_{ij}$ are the unique metric-compatible connection coefficients and $\tau$ is the arc length parameter (i.e. the proper time). To obtain a Newtonian limit, we'll first change the parametrization variable to $x^{0}=t$ using the chain rule to obtain

$$\frac{d^{2}q^{k}(t)}{dt^{2}} = -\Gamma^{k}_{ij}\frac{dq^{i}(t)}{dt}\frac{dq^{i}(t)}{dt}+\Gamma^{0}_{ij}\frac{dq^{k}(t)}{dt}\frac{dq^{i}(t)}{dt}\frac{dq^{i}(t)}{dt}.$$

This expression vanishes identically for $k=0$ as expected, so we now only look at terms with $k\neq 0.$ We write this in powers of the velocity $v^{k}(t)=\frac{dq^{k}(t)}{dt}$ to obtain the famous result that

$$\frac{d^{2}q^{k}(t)}{dt^{2}} = -\Gamma^{k}_{00}-2\sum\limits_{j\neq 0}\Gamma^{k}_{0j}v^{j}(t)-\sum\limits_{i,j\neq 0}\Gamma^{k}_{ij}v^{i}(t)v^{j}(t)+\Gamma^{0}_{ij}\frac{dq^{i}(t)}{dt}\frac{dq^{i}(t)}{dt}v^{k}(t)=-\Gamma^{k}_{00}+\mathcal{O}(v).$$

So we have that the acceleration is $a^{k}(t)\sim-\Gamma^{k}_{00}$ as $v\searrow  0$. We move on to estimating the effect of a small perturbation to the Minkowski metric. This is where I get something weird. For $\epsilon>0,$ suppose the metric tensor takes the form $$\textbf{g}=\boldsymbol{\eta}+\epsilon \textbf{h}=\boldsymbol{\eta}(\textbf{1}+\epsilon\boldsymbol{\eta}\textbf{h})$$ where $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ is the ordinary Minkowski metric and $\textbf{h}$ is a matrix depending on the coordinates. We expand the inverse metric in powers of $\epsilon$ using the Neumann series to obtain $$ \textbf{g}^{-1}=(\textbf{1}+\epsilon\boldsymbol{\eta}\textbf{h})^{-1}\boldsymbol{\eta}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-\epsilon\boldsymbol{\eta}\textbf{h})^{n}\boldsymbol{\eta}=\boldsymbol{\eta}-\epsilon\boldsymbol{\eta}\textbf{h}\boldsymbol{\eta}+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{2}).$$

So the inverse metric's components are $g^{ij}\sim \eta^{ij}-\epsilon \eta^{im}\eta^{jn}h_{mn}$ as $\epsilon\searrow 0.$ We now express the connection coefficients in terms of the metric. For $k\neq 0$, this gives us $$a^{k}(t)\sim-\Gamma^{k}_{00}=\frac{1}{2}g^{k\ell}(\partial_{\ell}g_{00}-2\partial_{0}g_{0\ell})\sim\frac{1}{2}(\eta^{k\ell}-\epsilon \eta^{km}\eta^{\ell n}h_{mn})(\epsilon\partial_{\ell}h_{00}-2\epsilon\partial_{0}h_{0\ell})\\ \sim \frac{\epsilon}{2}\eta^{k\ell}\partial_{\ell}h_{00}-\epsilon\eta^{k\ell}\partial_{0}h_{0\ell}+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{2}).$$
So the components of the acceleration in this limit are $\boxed{a_{k}(t) \sim -\frac{\epsilon}{2}\partial_{k}h_{00}+\epsilon\partial_{0}h_{0k}}$

The 1st term is correct, as it ends up containing the Newtonian potential. But the 2nd term $\epsilon\partial_{0}h_{0k}$ isn't supposed to be included in the final answer. Is there a reason it should vanish?

After obtaining this, I found https://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/ where it states that a 3rd assumption in the Newtonian limit is that the metric is static. This would, of course, kill the 2nd anomalous term. But this is strange to me, since these two terms seem to have the same relative size. Can't Newtonian gravity handle time-varying gravitational fields? Why is this static assumption made in the Newtonian limit, and does this 2nd term have any physical meaning?

Comment: The first term refers to the change of the time dilation over distance. The second term refers to the change of the time dilation over time. Since the cause of gravity is a gradient of the time dilation, your result seems perfectly intuitive and refers to the Newtonian limit with a variable mass.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211930/2451

Comment: The assumption that everything is moving slowly (i.e. non-relativistic), immediately implies that the Newtonian gravitational potential is only slowly varying. Differently, put the time derivative term of the metric is of similar order as some of the higher velocity terms you dropped in the geodesic calculation.

Comment: It’s important to remember that the passage of time is relative to the speed & mass of the objects where it is measured. Newton didn’t know that the speed an apple drops from the tree would be much slower if the tree were growing on a much more massive planet, that orbits it’s star at 660,000 mph & rotates on it’s axis at 10,000 mph. Newton’s physics work well enough within the parameters of life on the surface of this planet, beyond practical applications here on earth they are lacking.