# Is it possible to make a tiny approximation in the equations of General Relativity so that they collapse to Newton's law of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, approximations

GR and Newton give almost exactly the same result for the orbits of planets and the acceleration of falling bodies. Is it an incredible coincidence, or does GR have some tiny term (e.g., ict) that accounts for the difference? Is it possible to make GR collapse to Newton's law by ignoring that tiny term?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211930/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yes, it is!  The effective potential in the Schwartzschild solution is equal to that in Newtonian gravitation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_potential) _plus_ a 1 / r^3 term that only kicks in very close to the body/black hole.  I didn't see any reference to this in the linked answers.

Comment: @Qmechanic please see my comment!

Comment: @jamesraymond please see my comment