# Limit from general relativity to Newtonian mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, classical-mechanics, approximations

What is the limit of general relativity to Newtonian  mechanics? Let me elaborate; from quantum mechanics to classical mechanics regime, we ignore the length of the Plancks $\hbar$, so we reached classical results. Now, how can we give this analogy while discussing the general theory of relativity \to classical mechanics or Newtonian mechanics?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211930/2451

Comment: Large radius of curvature (weak gravitation) _and_ low speed for all particles (non relativistic).