Why general relativity agrees with Newtonian theory in the limit?
I'm currently reading "The Large Scale Structure of Spacetime" by Hawking and Ellis. While the mathematical computations are clear to me, I find myself puzzled by the physics, particularly the assertion that "One would therefore obtain agreement with Newtonian theory in the limit of a weak field." Could you help clarify how general relativity converges with Newtonian gravity under these conditions? What are the physical meaning of the quantities?


The Newtonian limit is $\nabla^2 \phi = \delta^{ij} \partial_i \partial_j \phi = 4\pi G \rho$, where $\rho$ is the matter density and $\phi=f-1$. So the claim is that $\left(g^{\mu\nu} + V^\mu V^\nu \right)\nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu f = \delta^{ij} \partial_i \partial_j \phi$ when $g^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}$ (flat spacetime limit) and $V^\mu=\left(1, 0, 0, 0\right)$ (unit timelike vector). Showing that should just be a matter of plugging in and following your nose. As an aside, you may want to start with a more user-friendly book, like the ones by Hartle, Carroll, or Schutz, to name a few.

The other part of the claim is that $f R_{ab} V^a V^b$ reduces to $4\pi G \rho$ in the Newtonian limit, but that is what they are going to show. ("One would therefore obtain agreement... if the term on the right is equal to $4\pi G$ times the matter density plus terms which are small..."). The text after that explains what's needed for the right hand side to work out. The comment above is just clarifying what the Newtonian limit is, and what their logic is for the left hand side.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/211930/2451 and links therein.

Try seeing what the coordinate acceleration on a particle following a geodesic is for a Schwarzschild black hole with low mass/at large distance from the black hole.
